# How to ignore unknown words visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writting Python code and VSCode is underlining words and variables. How can I ignore it ?

Google says I should do :

"cSpell.diagnosticLevel": "Hint",

But what does it mean, should I write those lines in the terminal ?

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]
ANSWER : It was the Extension called "Code Spell Checker" which was analyzing the syntax. I disabled it and I'm not annoyed anymore.

Thanks Akshay to answer fast though.

Answer (score 12):

Go to settings in vs code -> write `cSpell.diagnosticLevel` inside box and choose hint from drop down